# concatenate the string in the txt file using powershell

Tags: email, powershell

I have a file "check1.txt which reads like this

```
     user1
     user2
     user3
```

I want to take this string from the file and put into a variable like this

```
   "user1@abc.com","user2@abc.com","user3@abc.com"
```

I use this pice of code :

```
  $variable1 = """" 
  $variable2 = (Get-content -path "C:\check1.txt") -join "@abc.com"","""



  $variable3 = $variable2 + "@abc.com"""
  $variable4 =  $variable1 + $variable3
     [String[]] $emailTo=$variable4
    [String[]] $emailCc="abcd6@xyz.com","abcd1@xyz.com"

 write-host $variable4 +"hi"

 write-host $emailTo +"To"
 write-host $emailCc +"Cc"
```

## Send the report email

```
Send-MailMessage -To $emailTo -Subject $subject -Body $Body -cc  $emailCc -SmtpServer $smtpServer -From $emailFrom -Priority $priority
```

but i m getting error like :

```
   "user1@abc.com","user2@abc.com","user3@abc.com" +hi

   "user1@abc.com","user2@abc.com","user3@abc.com" +To

   abcd@xyz.com abcd1@xyz.com +Cc

    Send-MailMessage : The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.
   At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\DisconnectedSession\mail.ps1:31 char:17
   + Send-MailMessage <<<<  -To $emailTo -Subject $subject -Body $Body -cc  $emailCc -SmtpServer $smtpServer -From $emailF
  rom -Priority $priority
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [Send-MailMessage], FormatException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

The issue is while both variable $emailTo and $emailCc are in same format as I have defined but for $emailTo , the script is interpreting it differently while for $emailCc, it is interpreting differently leading to the failure of the scipt.
Could anyone please suggest what to do for $emailTo as $emailCc is working fine as of now whatever has been assigned to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but I think that your `$emailTo` variable is wrong - it needs to be a string array.

You can construct it from your file as so:

```
$emailTo = @()
Get-content -path "C:\check1.txt" | % { $emailTo += ,"$_@abc.com" }
```

This will create an empty array and then iterate your user list, append the domain to each username and add the email address to the array

Comment: Thanks very much, I dont knwo why my script was not working...thanks once again for your effort. Kudos to you